# Can I extend the image field formatter without defining a custom one?

Tags: entities, 8, media

XY problem: I need to extend the default image widget in the entity edit form with some custom fields so that, per image, e.g. a copyright and description, independently from the alt and title field, can be set.

I can add the fields by altering the core image module files, and by manually adding the respective database columns. But of course, I would like to alter the plugins with a custom module.

I was able to create a custom formatter based on the ImageWidget as [described in this tutorial.](https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-custom-field-formatters-drupal-8/)

My question is: is there a way to alter the default image widget/ field type to add custom fields rather than defining custom formatters/ widgets?

Comment: I think you have a conceptual gag here in your concept. You want to make the image field to store new values (copyright, description). Widget is for the display. It won't able to display things, which doesn't exist in the field type. 
I would suggest you to rather create a content type for this (image field with two text fields) or even better a "weak entity", which can be provided by paragraph module.

Comment: well, can I then extend the field type without implementing my own? :)

Comment: Sure! You can extend the original field type, but you will have to rewrite some part of the @annotations (field type id for example). And then you also will have to extend the widget, to display the new values.  There are some HOWTO-s on drupal.org. Just search for 'create custom field type drupal 8'.

Comment: @ssibal i found out i can just use the existing plugin id in the annotations. is this bad practice or good?

Comment: Using the existing plugin id will mean you override the default (just because when the system parsing the plugin types your module is later I guess). 

In general I would always leave core things as they are, even from UI perspective. I can imagine a complex system, where you don't want to list elements which are never used, but in your case I would use a different ID, if that is possible.

Comment: @Alex, are you still working on this? I've built a few custom field formatters for D8 sites this year as well but agree with your reasoning that if all you want to do is add attributes to an existing field then extending an existing formatter is a good way to go. There may be D8 contrib modules that alter the options where you can add additional attributes.

Comment: we ended up with a pretty hacky way which is still causes errors, especially on updating entites and field definitions. no luck so far :/

Comment: I'm still doing some exploration to decide whether a new field is better than extending the existing one. Have a look at the Linked Field contrib module. They extend the image field and add attributes to the link that wraps around the image field. It's not what you're doing but might give you some insight to get there.

Comment: @AndrewWasson awesome, keep me up to date :) if you like, i can give you the code we have so far, which is buggy though

Comment: @Alex, I'll post back once I have a proof of concept up and running.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, more flexible way, you could chose to use either File entity or Media entity, both give you a fieldable entity that you can add your additional fields, without having to write a single line of custom code.

File entity makes the files themself fieldable and adds file types, so images can have different fields than videos for example.

Media entity adds a separate entity that you work with, and works well combined with a number of other modules like Entity Browser and Inline Entity Form. There are some good tutorials out there:

http://www.annertech.com/blog/reusable-media-drupal-8-tutorial
http://flocondetoile.fr/blog/managing-media-drupal-8

Comment: I know those modules, but they dont quite come up with what I need. The file entity module for instance does not show thumbnails. Also, once installed and uninstalled it seems the module is not working properly...

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do something similar to this in Drupal 8. I wanted to add a description field to the image field so that it could be displayed for each image.

I couldn't find a solution, so I ended up creating a custom module to do this. Ended up creating a custom field type, custom field widget and custom field formatter. Also using hook theme, a .field.inc to provide the variables for a template, and finally the said template.

This is one of the first pages I came across on Google searching for this, so I thought I'd add it in case it helps someone else.

https://github.com/WiddleWabbit/Drupal-ExtendedImage